# Overriding a Procedure in a Parent from a child control

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls, overriding, wndproc

I'm developing this usercontrol which requires I override the `WndProc` of the control's parent [which for all practical purposes is a Windows Form] and I'm stumped.

Ordinarily, I could drop the user on the form and manually override the forms `WndProc`.
Since my entire development team and possibly others I don't know of right now could be using it, I think it would be better I override from the UserControl.

Does anyone know how I can get this done? My preferred languages are VB.NET and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx), getting a reference to the parent form via `this.FindForm()`.

That is,

```
public class MyListener : NativeWindow
{
     public MyListener(UserControl myControl)
     {
         this.AssignHandle(myControl.FindForm().Handle);
     }

     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
     {
          // do stuff
          base.WndProc(ref m);
     }

     // dispose, etc.
}
```

Inheriting from `NativeWindow` in this way would let you intercept the Windows messages.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I'll try it out and see what happens.